Reactor context comes back empty
I'm trying to access the context from anywhere so I can get the headers and add this to a webclient builder object. The issue here is, the context always comes back empty with the following message: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty
Please, see my code below:
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
public class AsyncHeaderConfig implements WebFilter {
    private static final Class<ServerHttpRequest> CONTEXT_KEY = ServerHttpRequest.class;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .contextWrite(Context.of(CONTEXT_KEY, request));
    }

    public static Mono<ServerHttpRequest> getRequest() {
        return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> Mono.just(ctx.get(CONTEXT_KEY)));
    }

    public static ExchangeFilterFunction headerFilter() {
        return (request, next) -> getRequest().flatMap(r -> {
            ClientRequest clientRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
                                                       .headers(headers -> {
                                                           headers.set(X_CORRELATION_ID, r.getHeaders().getFirst("x-correlation-id"));
                                                           headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, r.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
                                                       })
                                                       .build();
            return next.exchange(clientRequest);
        });
    }
}

I test it using this controller:
@RestController
public class GetRequestController {

    @GetMapping("/request")
    public Mono<HttpHeaders> getRequest() {
        return AsyncHeaderConfig.getRequest()
                                .mapNotNull(request -> request.getHeaders());
    }
}

I've tried all the different approaches from these pages but still comes back with the same message! Link1, link2
